# Avoid flattening of query result on nested JSON with spark.sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a nested JSON file that I've loaded into dataset.

for example:

```
{"name":"Y", "address":{"city":"C","state":"O"}}
{"name":"M", "address":{"city":"h", "state":"C"}}
```

I want to write a sql query with spark.sql that extracts the nested fields but I need that the result structure will no be flattened, for example:

SELECT address.city FROM T1

will return column with the original two level of nesting :

```
address
-------
city
-------
c
h
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want this as your JSON for your question  ...   [{"name":"Y", "address":{"city":"C","state":"O"}},{"name":"M", "address":{"city":"h", "state":"C"}}]

Comment: Yes, the result should be a dataset that would have a nested jason structure as in the original structure.